# Postgres How to copy a complete table structure and all its constraints, riggers, checks

Tags: postgresql

I've tried "create table like  including all" , "create table () inherits "  and both only copy some of the elements.    How do you get a complete copy of the structure and all its components?

Comment: What are you missing with `create table like`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name `LIKE` will not copy FK's or triggers.

Comment: A quick and dirty way is to do something like  `pg_dump -d some_db -U some_user -t the_table -s -f the_table.sql`. This will create a plain text schema(-s) only definition of the table with all it components. You would have to do a find and replace in the file to rename it and its references in the dependent objects.